# Create table based on the data inserted in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains names of tables. Structure of all these tables is same which is also shown below. Whenever there is an additional row with new name of table in this table, I am to create a table with that name. I was looking for some way, that as soon as a new row with new name of table is inserted into following table, a new table with that name should be created automatically via some trigger or some other way.

```
ID  TableName
1   Electronics
2   Mechanical
3   Capacitor
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE Mechanical
(
ID INT,
ATTRIBUTE_1 VARCHAR2(25),
ATTRIBUTE_2 VARCHAR2(25),
ATTRIBUTE_3 VARCHAR2(25)
)
```

So as soon as we have a new row in the table with new table name, above table creation command should create a new table having the name of table inserted into the table.
Hope this explains the requirement.

Comment: In this case, instead of multiple tables you could simply create *one* table with one column referencing the parent row in the first table. This would be the preferred solution. That said Oracle also supports nested tables. Nested tables might the second best solution.

Comment: I'd consider having one, single attribute column only (and insert several rows if needed.)

Comment: Well for a toy application you will be happy with any approach, but in general neither the *key - value* nor the *col1, col2, col3_num, col4_date, ...* approaches scale very well. Anyway if you have a given structure identical for all you *subtypes* you may consider the *list partitioning*.

Comment: @jarlh this is the *optimal approach* if *never* need to *access* the data ...

Comment: This is a very scary requirement... it is as if someone wants to recreate a windows directory full of excel files in the database by creating a single table per excel file. This will work but the power of a relational database is completely missed... What is the reason for having additional identical tables ? (I can't think of any good one...)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As Alex Poole points out, you can do this with an autonomous transaction but it's not recommended since [it will leave orphan tables with rollbacks](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=263cb8d015531bd835bb87267d289f20).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_table(table_name in varchar2)
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'create table ' || table_name || ' (ID INT, ATTRIBUTE_1 VARCHAR2(25), ATTRIBUTE_2 VARCHAR2(25), ATTRIBUTE_3 VARCHAR2(25))';
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_table_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    create_table(:new.tablename);
END;
/
```

An alternative might be to create a scheduled job which checks the table every minute or so and creates new tables for any rows which don't already have existing tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE auto_create_tables
IS
BEGIN
  for t in (select tablename from my_table where tablename not in (select table_name from all_tables))
  loop
     execute immediate 'create table ' || t.tablename || ' (ID INT, ATTRIBUTE_1 VARCHAR2(25), ATTRIBUTE_2 VARCHAR2(25), ATTRIBUTE_3 VARCHAR2(25))';
  end loop;
END;
/
begin
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
         job_name             => 'auto_create_table_job',
         job_type             => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
         job_action           => 'auto_create_tables',
         start_date           => sysdate,
         repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1;',
         enabled              => TRUE);
end;
/
```

Comment: But this is DDL, which commits, and you can't commit in a trigger? Unless you make it autonomous I suppose, but then the insert can rollback and leave the new table behind. [As seen in this quick demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=263cb8d015531bd835bb87267d289f20).

Comment: Thanks, I always forget about that. Edited my answer.